# What's the default url that docker using when run `docker pull`?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've searched a lot but still can't get the accurate answer of this question:

What's the default url that docker using when run `docker pull`? (Especially the `/v2` one)

I've see several urls from log or some documents:

1. http://index.docker.io
2. http://registry.hub.docker.com
3. http://registry-1.docker.io

But I'm not sure which one is correct, and what's the purpose of the others

Answer (score 2):

Those 3 urls are there for different purposes:

http://registry.hub.docker.com is the Docker web site for listing the image.
It is not where those images are actually stored.

As the [Nexus Docker settings details](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/docker.html):

- https://registry-1.docker.io is a **remote storage**: [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15442) illustrates what is going on when the storage does not answer:

> This is a service issue, not related to the docker engine project.
>   Amazon S3 is experiencing some problems.

- https://index.docker.io/ is the docker index, used for requests related to searches, users, docker tokens and other aspects.

Answer (score 1):

To quote `man docker-pull`:

> If you do not specify a REGISTRY_HOST, the command uses Docker's public registry located at registry-1.docker.io by default.

I don't think you can get more official than that.